# What is RxJS's place in the JS ecosystem and evolution?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

To be clear, I'm hoping for factual information to be presented about RxJS and how it relates to JavaScript's evolution, not a matter of opinion on how good RxJS is, etc.

My question is: is RxJS ( https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS ) somewhat of a forward-looking polyfill because of [Object.observe](http://arv.github.io/ecmascript-object-observe/), etc. not being standard among browsers yet, or does it fundamentally offer things beyond the scope of what native JS offers *and* beyond what JS standards seek to offer in the foreseeable future? (Granted, perhaps someday native JS may be capable of X, Y, Z that aren't currently on the radar; I'm not interested in guesses on those.) Perhaps it's a combo.

My motivation/interest in the question is in considering the investment of learning and implementing RxJS in applications, weighed against the timeline of native JS solutions being available, and/or whether there are other considerations to be mentioned that I have not touched on here.

Comment: this question might be a good one to throw on quora.com

Comment: I think RxJs solves different problems (or at least in different ways) than the native syntax/features that ES is steering to.

Comment: quora links back to this post: https://www.quora.com/Is-RxJS-essentially-a-forward-looking-polyfill-because-of-Object-observe-not-being-standard-among-browsers-yet-or-does-it-fundamentally-offer-things-beyond-the-scope-of-what-native-JS-offers-and-beyond-what-JS-standards-seek-to-offer-in-the-foreseeable-future

Answer (score 28, accepted):

RxJS was birthed as a JavaScript port of Rx.NET.  It is not a forward looking polyfill of `Object.observe`.

RxJs is a library for working with asynchronous operations, with special emphasis on multi-valued operations.  The library gives the developer a common "language" they can use to write functional code to manipulate asynchronous streams no matter the stream source.  The same "language" works with any combination of UI events, timer events, object mutation observations, animation frames, ajax calls, websocket messages, webworker messages, promises, etc

`Object.observe` is a mechanism to observe changes in an object.  RxJS does not provide this functionality.  But RxJS complements this functionality:  As an object is changed over time, it can be thought of as a source of asynchronous object change notifications.  It is fairly straight-forward to convert these observations into an RxJS source, (e.g. something like `Rx.Observable.observeObject(someObject)`), which would then let you work with object changes as just another asynchronous RxJs stream with all of the vast array of tools RxJS makes available to you.

Answer (score 0):

RxJs is the library which helps us to do Reactive Programming.

Reactive Programming is a pattern of development that works with asynchronous data stream created of UI Events, HTTP Requests, File System, cache etc. So data stream is an ongoing event sequence in time orderly manner. The stream can emit value, error, and status signal.

Observables are to watch these streams and trigger function on anything occurs in the stream. Observers can subscribe to observables.

Ref- http://technobelities.blogspot.in/2017/02/rxjs-quick-start.html

As per MSDN -
Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style query operators. Reactive Extensions represents all these data sequences as observable sequences. An application can subscribe to these observable sequences to receive asynchronous notifications as new data arrive.